# Creating and Utilizing a Web Session

Tags: php, session, woocommerce, dropbox

I have been struggling to make Dropbox's "Saver Button" work properly with my on my Woocommerce based website. I currently have on customer's account page, so that they can download their digital purchases to their Dropbox.   When clicked, everything seems to work; the Dropbox pop up window with the correct file name comes up, and when you click "save," it does save the file to customers Dropbox account. However, if you attempt to download and view the PDF, you get this corrupt file message:

"Acrobat could not open 'myfile.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).”

Dropbox Customer Support led me to believe the issue is Woocommerce requires a new web session to access the supplied link. Any ideas on how to allow a new temporary web session for the Dropbox pop up window?

Comment: I might try testing the code as is but substituting a simple text file for the PDF.  If that opens fine it would certainly narrow things down.

Comment: I tried opening the a corrupted pdf, and it is a not pdf info at all. It is html that makes up the page that the Saver button or link appears on.

Comment: I am thinking creating a valid session may not be the best fix. Maybe the answer is to allow specific download links to not require any session at all.